# .net mvc GET blob:https://localhost:7116/7461d0c0-6eec-44f2-9470-ca393360f80b net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to display a preview of an image(s) before the user submits them with the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#imageUploader").change(function () {
        document.getElementById('imgViewer').src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    });
});
```

but I'm just getting this undescriptve error that is apparently possibly related to CORS:

`blob:https://localhost:7116/7461d0c0-6eec-44f2-9470-ca393360f80b net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)`

I've googled around and tried all the CORS settings on my app but to no avail. e.g. adding

```
builder.Services.AddCors();
```

and the below in program.cs.

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
            );
```

When I go that url in the browser i get a blank page and the same error and trying the url in postman just gives an invalid url error. How do I fix the error and get the image preview to display?

### Update

I'm now trying to post the image to my server and then upload it to blob storage so I can use the hosted url instead. However I can't post an image, via ajax, to my server either - same error! Which also alludes to a CORS error. Though, the ajax request works fine for text data, just not with the image. Is there a setting I need to change to allow image/binary data to be posted to the server? (The data is posted with a normal form submit)

```
$("#imageUploader").change(function () {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("Images", event.target.files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/rating/SubmitPreviewImage',
        headers: {
            "RequestVerificationToken":
                $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
        },
        type: 'post',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (imgUrl) {

        }
    });
});
```

Error:

```
POST https://localhost:7116/rating/SubmitPreviewImage net::ERR_FAILED
```

### Update 2

So if I click the submit button the image gets posted to the server no problem, but if I submit the form via javascript it doens't!? It doesn't work via a crafted postman request either. Literally only clicking the button works, what on earth!?

```
$("#imageUploader").change(function () {
    $('#msform').submit();
});
```

### Update 3

Same error when following this guide for a MAUI app too...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/images?view=aspnetcore-6.0#preview-an-image-provided-by-the-inputfile-component

### Update 4

Now it's getting weird. The original image posting has stopped working, literally just submitting the form to the server. I even checked out the branch which is working on live to test and that isn't working. So something on my machine must've changed since installing MAUI?? I'm so confused, pls hlp

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled IIS Express and now it works... Maddening